# I'm having trouble understanding this for loop and what its returning

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def double_char(str):
    result = ''
    for char in str:
        result += char + char
    return result
```

this is the function, and when i call it, say:

```
double_char(dog)
```

it returns: 'ddoogg'

but on line 4 it's saying result = result + char + char wouldn't that yield ''dogdog? I'm really confused and I think I just dont understand the basics of for loops

Comment: `for char in str` is going to iterate over each character in the string, and on each iteration `char` is going to hold the value of the `n`th character in the string. Appending these characters to the string results in the same string as input, but with each character repeated twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try running the function:

```
def double_char(string):
    result = ''
    for char in string:
        result += char + char
    return result

print(double_char('dog'))
```

It returns:

```
ddoogg
```

So, what this function is doing is defining an emptry string (`result`).  Many programs do this, they have a temporary empty string.  Then that string gets filled up with new information generated by a loop (`for char in string:`).  This loop loops through every character in the string, so `d`, `o`, and `g`.  However, there is a twist.  This code adds two of the same character for every character inside of the string so, it goes `result += 'd' + 'd'` on the first iteration.  And then `result += 'o' + 'o'`.  The `+=` operater is simply squishing two strings together, like `dd` from the first iteration with `oo` from the second iteration.  From there, we get `ddoo`. And it continues until the end of the string.  Finally, we use the `return` statement to send out the new temporary string we created, `result`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over each character in the string. Imagine it was just:

```
for char in str:
    print char
```

you go 'd', 'o', 'g' resulting in "dog". Now do the same but 2 times:

```
for char in str:
    print char
    print char
```

you are going 'd', 'd', 'o', 'o' ... resulting in "ddoogg". You are doing the same but constructing the string, then printing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your method like this to get what you want.

```
def double_char(str):
    result = str + str
    return result
```

`for char in str:` loops through every character in str. First time is `'d'`, second is `'o'`, third is `'g'`. Each of these gets doubled and added to the result. In other words, the first value is **not** just `'dog'` as a whole.

`result` then looks like this after every iteration

```
''
'dd'
'ddoo'
'ddoogg'
```

Answer (score 0):

In python when you run for loop on element like string,
You actually iterate over its characters.
That's why in your example you get each characters twice.
For 'dogdog' use: `result = 2*'dog'`

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, you are passing string 'dog', implies `str:='dog'`

Initialised, 
`result=''`
This will initialise result to empty string once.

```
for char in str:
```

This loop will iterate through every char.

```
result += char + char
```

when you iterate through the loop. char will represent  'd','o','g' respectively at each iteration.

```
iteration 1:
result=''
char + char := 'd'+'d'
```

exiting from iteration : result ='dd'

```
iteration 2:
result='dd'
char + char := 'o'+'o'
```

exiting from iteration : result ='dd'

```
iteration 3:
result='ddoo'
char + char := 'g'+'g'
```

exiting from iteration : `result ='ddoogg'`

loop finished

if you want to return 'dogdog'

simply do:

```
def double_char(str):
    return str+str
```